# JAXB - How to set the xsi:type of a XML element based on its value?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I have to generate a xml element  that can have as value any "primitive type" (xsd:string, xsd:boolean, etc). Examples:

```
<field xsi:type="xsd:string" name="aString">String Value</field>
<field xsi:type="xsd:date" name="aDate">2011-10-21</field>
...
```

So, I tried two implementations:

```
public class Field {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    Object value;
}
```

and ...

```
public class Field<T> {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    T value;
}
```

I'm testing this with:

```
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Field.class).createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);

Field field = new Field();
field.name = "name";
field.value = "value";

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
marshaller.marshal(field, new PrintWriter(stream));
System.out.println(stream);
```

But I'm getting this `NullPointerException` when I try to instantiate the JAXBContext.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:165)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ValueProperty.<init>(ValueProperty.java:77)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:106)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:515)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:330)
at
```

The idea is allow schema validation for the field element (It is define in a schema must its type will be set in each instance). So, even is this a Bug (or not) ... how JAXB will put the correct `xsi:type` to this field instance? I'm missing a concept here?

I know that maybe the problem is the usage of the `@XmlValue` because of this restrictions (from the javadoc):

> - At most one field or property can be annotated with the @XmlValue annotation.
> - @XmlValue can be used with the following annotations: XmlList. However this is redundant since XmlList maps a type to a simple schema type that derives by list just as XmlValue would.
> - If the type of the field or property is a collection type, then the collection item type must map to a simple schema type.
> - If the type of the field or property is not a collection type, then the type must map to a XML Schema simple type.

... because an `Object` or a generic `T` is not necessarily a XML Schema simple type, this approach seems not to be the correct one ...

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed the issue you are seeing in both the reference and [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementations of JAXB.  The problem you are seeing is due to use of `@XmlValue`.  If the `value` property was mapped as an `@XmlElement` you would see the `xsi:type` attribute appear as expected.

I have entered the following bug to track this issue in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/361689

Depending upon what your domain model looks like you may be interested in the `@XmlPath` extension from EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

**UPDATE**

This issue has now been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.3.3 and EclipseLink 2.4.0.  The fix is available in these streams starting March 17, 2012 and can be obtained from:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: Thanks for the response Blaise ... I will keep your options in mind (and the bug too).